# A function with some differential equation properties.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I am dealing with a family of functions that take the form $$y(x)=-\frac{f(x)}{(x-1)^{2v+1}}.$$ By taking $y'(x)$, we obtain a new rational function $$y'(x)=\frac{g(x)}{(x-1)^{2v+2}}.$$ What I notice is that although $f(x)\neq g(x)$, it is always the case that $$(2v+1)f(1)=g(1).$$

Here are some examples:

Consider
\begin{align*}
y(x)=-\frac{(3x^2+12x)}{(x-1)^7}.\tag1
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
y'(x)=\frac{15x^2+78x+12}{(x-1)^8}
\end{align*}

Although $3x^2+12x\neq 15x^2+78x+12$, we have $$(2*3+1)(3(1)^2+12(1))=15(1)^2+78(1)+12$$

---

Another example: Let $$y(x)=-\frac{(-5x^3+10x^2+100x)}{(x-1)^9}$$ We have $$y'(x)=\frac{(100 + 820 x + 55 x^2 - 30 x^3)}{(x-1)^{10}}$$ Observe that $$9*(-5+10+100)=-30+55+820+100$$

---

Is there a general solution to  $(2v+1)f(1)=g(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the denominator is a power of $(x-1)$.

To see what happens, just take the derivative: if $\displaystyle y(x)=-\frac{f(x)}{(x-1)^{2v+1}}$, then
$$\begin{multline*} y'(x)=-\frac{f'(x)(x-1)^{2v+1}-f(x)(2v+1)(x-1)^{2v}}{(x-1)^{4v+2}}= \\
=-\frac{f'(x)(x-1)-f(x)(2v+1)}{(x-1)^{2v+2}}=\frac{(2v+1)f(x)-(x-1)f'(x)}{(x-1)^{2v+2}}.\end{multline*}$$

So you can see that the numerator that you denoted by $g(x)$ is
$$g(x)=(2v+1)f(x)-(x-1)f'(x).$$

Plugging in $x=1$, you get that
$$g(1)=(2v+1)f(1)-(1-1)f'(1)=(2v+1)f(1).$$